# Socket programming client send and receive file at same time

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying this scenario:

1. Client sends file to server
2. Server updates on file and save it
3. Sends updated file back to client

Steps 1 and 2 are done correctly as I wanted but when client finishes sending the socket closes. I've tried this code but its not working. Any suggestions?

Client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
H = socket.gethostname()            
P = 1111
s.connect((H,P))

with open('File.txt', 'rb') as fileName:
    for data in fileName:
        s.sendall(data)

with open('ReFile.txt', 'wb') as File:
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print data
        if not data:
            break
        File.write(data)
    File.close()
```

Server:

```
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
H= socket.gethostname()            
P = 1111
s.bind((H, P))
s.listen(6)

c, address = s.accept()
print 'Connection with ' , address

with open('ReFile.txt', 'wb') as RecFile:
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        print data
        if not data:
            break
        RecFile.write(data)
    RecFile.write("updated version")
    RecFile.close()

with open('ReFile.txt', 'rb') as file:
 for data in file:
  s.sendall(data)

s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Server:**

```
import socket


s = socket.socket()
H = socket.gethostname()
P = 1111
s.bind((H, P))
s.listen(6)

c, address = s.accept()
print 'Connection with ', address

lenF = int(c.recv(1024))

if lenF != 0:
    c.sendall('Send data')
    data = c.recv(lenF)
    data += "\nUpdated Version"
    RecFile = open('ReFile.txt','w')
    RecFile.write(str(data))
    RecFile.close()

fileN = open('ReFile.txt')
data = fileN.read(-1)
fileN.close()
lenF = len(data)
c.send(str(lenF))
if c.recv(5) == 'Ready':
    c.send(data)
```

Here I am using `lenF` variable to get the size of file that I am getting from the client.

**Client:**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
H = socket.gethostname()
P = 1111
s.connect((H,P))


fileName = open('file.txt')
data = fileName.read(-1)
fileName.close()
dataL = int(len(data))
s.send(str(dataL))
validCheck = s.recv(9)
if validCheck == 'Send data':
    print 'Sending file.......'
    s.send(data)


dataL = int(s.recv(1024))
if dataL != 0:
    s.send('Ready')
    data = s.recv(dataL)
    File = open('ReFile.txt','w')
    File.write(data)
    File.close()
```

Here I am using `dataL` variable to receive data length(file) and sending it.